# Ffmpeg: Concat multiple videos and an audio file. Videos may or may not have audio and I cant know it before runnign the command

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a list of mp4 and an aac audio file. I have a concat.txt file with all the mp4s that need to be concatenated.
I need to concat all the mp4s and merge the aac on top.

As said in the title, the mp4s individually may or may not have an audio track, and I can not check the mp4s with no audio, add a dummy sound track as it will be an automated process with thousands of commands executed daily.

The sound of the mp4, if present, must be preserved and merged with the aac

Here is a working command for the case where at least the first of my mp4s has an audiotrack:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i concat.txt -i audio.aac  -c:v copy -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a] amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest [audio_out]" -map 0:v -map "[audio_out]" -y result.mp4
```

However that breaks if my mp4s dont have audio

> Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0:a][1:a]
> amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest [audio_out] matches no streams.

I've been reading about anullsrc, and would like to take [0:a] if it exists, or a generated empty audio channel, and merge it with my aac, but I'm not getting there.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
#LST=($(ls -1tr *.mp4))
LST=("input 1.mp4" "only_video.mp4" "1280x720x30_2.mp4")
#LST=("1280x720x30_1.mp4" "only_video.mp4" "1280x720x30_2.mp4")
f="${LST[0]}"

IFS=, read VID WID HEI SAR FMT FPS TBN <<< $(ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name,width,height,sample_aspect_ratio,r_frame_rate,time_base,pix_fmt -of csv=p=0 "$f")
echo $VID $WID $HEI $SAR $FMT $FPS $TBN
if [ "$SAR" = "N/A" ]; then SAR=1; fi
#FPS=30
TBN=${TBN#*/}
echo $VID $WID $HEI $SAR $FMT $FPS $TBN

IFS=, read AUD SRA CHL <<< $(ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name,channel_layout,sample_rate -of csv=p=0 "$f")
echo $AUD $SRA $CHL

TXT=list.txt
mkdir out
o="out/${f%.*}.mkv"
ffmpeg -i "$f" -c copy "$o" -y -hide_banner
echo "file '$o'" > $TXT

for (( i=1; i<${#LST[@]}; i++ )); do
  f="${LST[$i]}"
  o="out/${f%.*}.mkv"
  AU2=$(ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$f")
  if [ "$AU2" = "" ]; then
    echo --- create empty audio
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:v copy -c:a $AUD -q:a 5 -shortest "$o" -y -hide_banner
  else
    if [ "$AU2" = "$AUD" ]; then
      echo --- copy audio
      ffmpeg -i "$f" -c copy "$o" -y -hide_banner
    else
      echo --- encode audio
      ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v copy -c:a $AUD -q:a 5 -shortest "$o" -y -hide_banner
    fi
  fi
  echo "file '$o'" >> $TXT
done

cat "$TXT"
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "$TXT" -i "input 3.mp3" -filter_complex "
[0:a][1:a] amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest
" -c:v copy -c:a aac out/output.mp4 -y -hide_banner

mpv out/output.mp4
```

it was simplified and edited part of script

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not precise enough in my question (i was looking to generate dynamic cmd to be run by a c# process, but your answer sent me the right way, thanks :)